Schwarz-Christoffel transformation of rectangle
I have a rectangle of known aspect ratio $\frac{L_y}{L_x}$. While not necessary, assume that the rectangle is in the first quadrant of the XY-plane with the points given as:
$z_1 = (0, L_y)$, $z_2 = (0, 0)$, $z_3 = (L_x, 0)$ and $z_4 = (L_x, L_y)$.
The mapping from $t = t_r + \imath t_i$ to $z=z_r + \imath z_i$ can be given by
\begin{equation}
dz = \frac{Adt}{\sqrt{(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)(t-\gamma)(t-\delta)}}
\end{equation}
The mapping can also be given in terms of elliptic functions where $z_1\to t =\frac{-1}{k}$, $z_2\to t = -1$, $z_3\to t = 1$, and $z_4 \to t=\frac{1}{k}$ where k is the modulus of elliptic function of first kind.
Since we know $\frac{\Vert\bar{z_1z_2}\Vert}{\Vert\bar{z_2z_3}\Vert}=\frac{L_y}{L_x}=\frac{K'(k)}{2K(k)}$, we can solve for $k$.
H. F. Moulton (1905) writes that $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$ can be picked arbitrarily provided that
\begin{equation}
\frac{(\beta - \gamma)(\alpha - \delta)}{(\alpha - \gamma)(\beta - \delta)}=k^2
\end{equation}
where $k$ gives $\frac{L_y}{L_x}=\frac{K'(k)}{K(k)}$.
Can someone explain how the expression given by Moulton can be obtained from the generic expression of Schwarz-Christoffel transformation? I cannot relate Moulton's expression to the expectation that 3 parameters of the Schwarz-Christoffel transformation can be picked arbitrarily.
